# Combined ANY/ALL (AND/OR) in GravityForms GFAPI::get_entries?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Can `GFAPI::get_entries` take a NESTED set of `field_filters`, so the top filter uses `'mode' => 'all'` and the child filter uses `'mode' => 'any'` ?

My goal is to find entries where
`Color = 'Red'` **AND** `City = 'Chicago' OR 'Boston'`

The docs for GFAPI do not mention this capability, but there are not many examples anyway. I tried the following code, but it results in a 500-error.

```
$form_id         = '11';
$search_criteria = array(
        'field_filters' => array(
                'mode' => 'all'  // 'and'; default
                array(
                        'key'   => '23', // color
                        'value' => 'red'
                ),
                array(
                        'mode' => 'any', // 'or'
                        array(
                                'key'   => '12', // city
                                'value' => 'Chicago'
                        ),
                        array(
                                'key'   => '12',
                                'value' => 'Boston'
                        ),
                ),
        ) // field_filters
); // $search_criteria
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria );
```

Alternatively, I can do the 2nd filter (for City) separately, in a foreach ($entries as $entry), if necessary.

Wondering if anyone has tried something like this and could advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with the `GFAPI::get_entries` method; however, if you're willing to go beneath the hood a little further, you can use the `GF_Query` class to do complex clauses as you've described.

Take a look at this [simple form export](https://gwiz.io/34NrcZt). I've setup two Drop Down fields, each with three choices. I've submitted three sample entries:

[image: Sample Entries]

Now, let's say we only want to get entries where Drop Down A is "First Choice" and Drop Down B is "Second Choice" *or* "Third Choice". That'd look something like this:

```php
$form_id = 387;
$gf_query = new GF_Query( $form_id );
$gf_query->where( call_user_func_array( array( 'GF_Query_Condition', '_and' ), array(
    new GF_Query_Condition(
        new GF_Query_Column( '1' ),
        GF_Query_Condition::EQ,
        new GF_Query_Literal( 'First Choice' )
    ),
    call_user_func_array( array( 'GF_Query_Condition', '_or' ), array(
        new GF_Query_Condition(
            new GF_Query_Column( '2' ),
            GF_Query_Condition::EQ,
            new GF_Query_Literal( 'Second Choice' )
        ),
        new GF_Query_Condition(
            new GF_Query_Column( '2' ),
            GF_Query_Condition::EQ,
            new GF_Query_Literal( 'Third Choice' )
        ),
    ) ),
) ) );

$entries = $gf_query->get();
```

This is the same basic structure as your example with the color and city. Just update the form ID, field IDs, and field values and you'll be good to go.